XVM Ink Wasm to EVM: Contract Reverted. Decoding Failed
I tried to deploy a XVM Wasm contract wrapping around a deployed EVM Solidity contract in my local node.
Steps

Deploy my EVM Solidity contract via Remix connecting to my local node

//SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.21;

contract Storage {
    uint256 number;
    
    function store(uint256 num) public {
        number = num;
    }
    function retrieve() public view returns (uint256) {
        return number;
    }
}


Write XVM Wasm contract:

#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std, no_main)] //added "no_main"

/// EVM ID (from astar runtime)
const EVM_ID: u8 = 0x0F;

#[ink::contract(env = xvm_environment::XvmDefaultEnvironment)]
mod store_xvm {
    use ethabi::{
        ethereum_types::{
            H160,
            U256,
        },
        Token,
    };
    use hex_literal::hex;
    use ink::prelude::vec::Vec;

    const STORE_SELECTOR: [u8; 4] = hex!["6057361d"];

    #[ink(storage)]
    pub struct StoreXvm {
        evm_address: [u8; 20],
    }

    impl StoreXvm {
        #[ink(constructor)]
        pub fn new(evm_address: [u8; 20]) -> Self {
            Self { evm_address }
        }

        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn store(&mut self, value: u128) -> bool {
            let encoded_input = Self::store_encode( value.into());
            self.env()
                .extension()
                .xvm_call(
                    super::EVM_ID,
                    Vec::from(self.evm_address.as_ref()),
                    encoded_input, 0
                )
                .is_ok()
        }

        fn store_encode(value: U256) -> Vec<u8> {
            let mut encoded = STORE_SELECTOR.to_vec();
            let input = [Token::Uint(value)];
            encoded.extend(&ethabi::encode(&input));
            encoded
        }

    }

}

My Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "store_xvm"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["[your_name] <[your_email]>"]
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
ink = { version = "4.3.0", default-features = false }

scale = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "3", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }
scale-info = { version = "2.5", default-features = false, features = ["derive"], optional = true }

ethabi = { git = "https://github.com/akru/ethabi", default-features = false }

hex-literal = "0.4.1"
xvm-environment = { path = "../../lib/xvm-environment", default-features = false }

[lib]
path = "lib.rs"

[features]
default = ["std"]
std = [
    "ink/std",
    "scale/std",
    "scale-info/std",
    "xvm-environment/std",
]
ink-as-dependency = []


Compile my XVM Wasm contract:

$ cargo contract build

cargo contract version is 3.2.0, good for my Wasm Ink! 4.3.0 version
Compilation successful with
  - store_xvm.contract (code + metadata)
  - store_xvm.wasm (the contract's code)
  - store_xvm.json (the contract's metadata)


Use https://ui.use.ink/ to deploy the compiled wasm with Solidity contract address.

Then I got Contract Reverted! DispatchError: DecodingFailed Input passed to a contract API function failed to decode as expected type...
Code Repo: https://github.com/AuroraLantean/ink-xvm-sdk
Reference:
https://medium.com/astar-network/cross-virtual-machine-creating-a-portal-to-the-future-of-smart-contracts-a96c6d2f79b8
https://theastarbulletin.news/how-to-implement-a-contract-using-xvm-1c94d2072c30
https://docs.astar.network/docs/learn/interoperability/xvm/#interfaces
Code are copied from https://github.com/realtakahashi/ink-xvm-sdk and https://github.com/AstarNetwork/ink-xvm-sdk

It is okay to use the latest solidity 0.8.25 and the latest cargo contract v4.1.1.
Although https://ui.use.ink/ says Contract Reverted. Decoding Failed, that is OKAY!
Go to https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/contracts and follow the tutorial link posted above
